# Skunk gecko please help

Tags: health, reptiles, leopard-geckos

My skunk gecko mouth is half way open and looks like her chest is caved in nothing has happened to her she lives alone eats only crickets and in a very clean environment please help I don't know what to do or what is wrong

Comment: Can you provide more information? Is the gekko alive/responsive? By 'Nothing has happened to her' do you mean that no major incident has happened? It would seem that something _has_ happened to her to cause this. Any other relevant information you can provide will help people answer this.

Comment: Take her to the vet urgently - Does she have fresh water?  also please include a photo and more details as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Can you post pictures? Reptiles regulate heat by keeping their mouths open.